# Множественное число от слова "софа"

Tags: морфология

Недавно покупала кровать и столкнулась с тем, что не знаю, как правильно употребить слово "софа" во множественном числе. Помогите, пожалуйста: как правильно сказать?
Спасибо

Comment: Недавно покупал чайник и столкнулся с тем, что не знаю, как правильно употребить слово "самовар" во множественном числе.

Comment: >Недавно покупал чайник и столкнулся с тем, что не знаю, как правильно употребить слово "самовар" во множественном числе.  
  
"Виндуз для чайников" Вам в помощь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никаких проблем: с**о**фы.
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%F1%EE%F4%E0&all=x

Вот в косвенных падежах возникают некоторые разночтения: с**о**фам - общая норма, Лопатин наряду с ней допускает соф**а**м (мне кажется, несколько опрометчиво), аналогично - в творительном и предложном.